# UITableView crashes when trying to scroll (stuck on this for hours)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have been trying to fix this problem for hours. My app keeps crashing when I try to scroll. I looked in to the reusable section but am still stuck.

UPDATE: I am running xcode 4.2 with ARC & I am having bad access error.

UPDATE 2: I tried to locate the problem using Zombies but am still unable to fix the issue.
screenshot of zombies: http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/7651/instruments.png

UPDATE 3 [problem solved]: I made sure all outlets were [self set___:nil] in the ViewDidUnload. I also created a property for the added view instead of creating the view in the .m file.
THe comment at the bottom here helped me out too:
[get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when trying  dismissModalViewController after parent view controller has been viewDidUnload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330503/get-exc-bad-access-when-trying-dismissmodalviewcontroller-after-parent-view-c)

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.sortedKeys count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    listData2 =[self.tableContents objectForKey:
    [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
    return [listData2 count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    questionTitle = [[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex: [indexPath section]]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Foobar"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Foobar"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = questionTitle;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what are the crash details?  Is it BAD_ACCESS or similar?  Providing these types of details in addition to posting code is very helpful.

Comment: main.m `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));` Program received signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: turn on NSZombies, and it will tell you which deallocated object is being messaged.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out why things are being deallocated using NSZombie . I get this [LINK TO IMAGE](http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/7651/instruments.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting questionTitle in your cellForRowAtIndexPath which is (presumably) a property of your ViewController, define a local string:

```
NSString *questionTitle2 = ...
```

and then use that to set the cell label:

```
cell.textLabel.text = questionTitle2;
```

Does that make any difference?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

A trace stack would be really helpful, but I also believe that you should move `listData2 = ..` to `viewWillApear:`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    listData2 =[self.tableContents objectForKey: [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [listData2 count];
}
```

Also, try to add `NSLogs` to your  other `UITableView` methods, for example:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInTableView: self.sortedKeys count: %i",[self.sortedKeys count]);
    return [self.sortedKeys count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"titleForHeaderInSection: self.sortedKeys object: %@"[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]);
    return [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Comment: how would I get the selection variable if I moved it to viewWillAppear?

Comment: Gasp. I must have overlooked that object.